# Javafx MediaPlayer unstable when running multiple files

Tags: javafx

I have a command to run the list of audio files as follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] listFiles = new File(folder).listFiles();
        ObservableList<Media> mediaList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (File listFile : listFiles) {
            mediaList.add(new Media(new File(listFile.getAbsolutePath()).toURI().toString()));
        }
        playMediaTracks(mediaList);
}

private static void playMediaTracks(ObservableList<Media> mediaList) {
        if (!mediaList.isEmpty()) {
            MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(mediaList.remove(0));
            mediaplayer.play();

            mediaplayer.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
                playMediaTracks(mediaList);
            });
        }
    }
```

Operation code is not stable,I have 10 audio files but sometimes only 2 or 3 files are stopped.But the program does not report bugs,I do not know how to fix. Please help me

Comment: Try moving `mediaplayer.play()` to the last line after the `setOnEndOfMedia()`.

Comment: I tried it but it was still unstable

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the media player being disposed since it has no strong references. Try introducing a field holding the currently-active media player.

Comment: I'm new to this genre media the first time,you can give me a little hint

Comment: Have something like `static MediaPlayer mediaplayer;`, and use this instead of declaring a variable inside `playMediaTracks`...

Comment: Thank @Itai I checked with your suggestion carefully, I noticed the program was working properly